# How do I return a printf statement if the user inputs nothing?

Tags: c

I want to execute a statement based on the input of the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {

   char string_input[40];
   int i;

   printf("Enter data ==>  ");
      scanf("%s", string_input);

   if (string_input[0] == '\n') {
      printf("ERROR - no data\n"); 
      }
   else if (strlen(string_input) > 40) {
      printf("Hex equivalent is       ");
      }
   else {
      printf("Hex equivalent is       ");
      }

}
```

When I run it, and just press enter, it goes to a new line instead of saying "ERROR - no data".

What do I do?

**CANNOT USE FGETS as we have not gone over this in class.**

Comment: And what would you want it to do instead? No input - it branches to "no input".

Comment: Does the 'magic quit' _have_ to be a blank line?

Comment: Yes it does. Has to work for a space and enter.

Comment: misleading answer (heading).. it should look like - how to get user input without fgets()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
char enter[1];
int chk = scanf("%39[^\n]%c", string_input, enter);
```

but `string_input` will not have a `'\n'` inside. Your test

```
   if (string_input[0] == '\n') {
       printf("ERROR - no data\n");
   }
```

will have to be changed to, for example

```
   if (chk != 2) {
       printf("ERROR - bad data\n");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. `scanf` doesn't check if user enters a string longer than 40 chars in your example above so for your particular case `fgets` should be simpler(safer).

Comment: We have not gone over fgets in class thus I can not use it. My friend mentioned using `gets` but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a while loop and getch, then test for the `<Enter>` key on each keystroke?

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` won't return until it sees something other than whitespace. It also doesn't distinguish between newlines and other whitespace. In practice, using `scanf` is almost always a mistake; I suggest that you call `fgets` instead and then (if you need to) use `sscanf` on the resulting data.

If you do that, you really ought to deal with the possibility that the user enters a line longer than the buffer you pass to `fgets`; you can tell when this has happened because your entire buffer gets filled and the last character isn't a newline. In that situation, you should reallocate a larger buffer and `fgets` again onto the end of it, and repeat until either you see a newline or the buffer gets unreasonably large.

You should really be similarly careful when calling `scanf` or `sscanf` -- what if the user enters a string 100 characters long? (You can tell `scanf` or `sscanf` to accept only a limited length of string.)

On the other hand, if this is just a toy program you can just make your buffer reasonably long and hope the user doesn't do anything nasty.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I cannot use fgets as we have not gone of it in class.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` does what you need.  Avoid using `scanf` or `gets`.  If you can't use `fgets` try using `getchar`

Comment: Your original posting said "not homework".  (f)scanf will keep reading until it finds a string, so I don't believe there is any way to test how many empty lines the user entered.  If you really can't use fgets fall back on getchar()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `"%s"` attempts to skip white-space, and then read a string -- and according to `scanf`, a new-line is "whitespace".

The obvious alternative would be to use `"%c"` instead of `"%s"`. The difference between the two is that `"%c"` does *not* attempt to skip leading whitespace.

A somewhat less obvious (or less known, anyway) alternative would be to use `"%[^\n]%*[\n]"`. This reads data until it encounters a new-line, then reads the new-line and doesn't assign it to anything.

Regardless of which conversion you use, you *want* (need, really) to limit the amount of input entered so it doesn't overflow the buffer you've provided, so you'd want to use `"%39c"` or `"%39[^\n]"`. Note that when you're specifying the length for `scanf`, you need to subtract one to leave space for the NUL terminator (in contrast to `fgets`, for which you specify the full buffer size).

Answer (score 0):

What platform are you running on?

Is the character sent when your press the ENTER key actually `'\n'`, or might it be `'\r'`? Or even both one after the other (ie. `"\r\n"`).